# Dynamic instrumentation vs Static Instrumentation

Tags: dynamic, static, instrumentation

In Static Instrumention, with reference to a sentence mentioned [here](http://www.ispras.ru/en/technologies/static_arm_binary_code_instrumentation/):

"Inserted instrumentation code is executed as a part of target executable or library providing the means to access internal data"

What about dynamic Instrumentation? Does that mean that with Dynamic Instrumentation the instrumented code does not run as part of the executable process? Is it correct to say that with Dynamic Instrumentation the instrumented code runs as separate process than the target?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not correct to say that, **in both cases the instrumentation is running in the same process as the application**.

The difference is the time that the instrumentation is added to the application. In the tool provided in the attached link, the instrumentation is added to the binary *before* the application is running, i.e. added to the "static" binary. While in Dynamic binary instrumentation frameworks (like [Pin](http://http:/https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/71313/Pin/html/) or [DynamoRIO](http://dynamorio.org/docs/%20DynamoRIO)) the instrumentation is added during the application execution in a JIT approach: While the application is running, the dynamic binary instrumentation framework is adding instrumentation (analysis code) to pieces of the application that are about to be executed.

Answer (score 3):

**Static Instrumentation :**
With static instrumentation, the instrumentation code is inserted into the class files of your application and then the updated class files are saved on disk.

```
public static void premain(String args , Instrumentation inst)
```

java -javaagent:=[options]

META-INF/MANIFEST.MF is required

**Dynamic Instrumentation :**
With dynamic instrumentation, the bytecode for you Java classes are instrumented at the time that they are loaded by the JVM.

```
public static void agentmain(String args , Instrumentation inst)
```

Executed when the *agent* attaches to the running JVM .

META-INF/MANIFEST.MF is required

Allows adding the code JVM post-factum